# Matrix row-wise indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array, e.g., the following

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

and also another numpy array with boolean values, e.g.,

```
I = np.array([[True, False, False], [False, True, False]])
```

I would like to get the matrix whose elements' indices are given by I. In the above example, I'd like to get the matrix

```
array([[1], [5]])
```

but if I try

```
B = A[I]
```

then I get

```
array([1, 5])
```

I understand that this is due to the fact that the number of `Trues`'s may not be the same in each row. But what about if they are? Is there any way of doing this using numpy?

In fact, I'd like to use this in Theano, using the `tensor` module. I have a theano expressions for the above (two `T.matrix` theano variables) that contain the above arrays. Is there any convenient way of computing the new, smaller matrix?

Comment: Can there be only one `True` value in each subarray? If yes, just use: `A[I, None]`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, no, there are many `True`'s in each subarray, but always the same number.

Comment: If you know the number, you can just reshape your array afterwards.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I see, didn't think of it. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can figure out how many items are returned from each row in advance, you can just reshape your output. I'd do it like this:

```
n = I.sum(1).max()
x = A[I].reshape(-1, n)

print(x)
array([[1],
       [5]])
```

Comment: Many thanks, it does the job! I have to wait 3 more minutes to accept your answer though :)